Прыгают блоки в размерах, до загрузки изображений/видео
Столкнулся с тем, что блок в котором расположено изображение. Тот же взять тег img или video...
Если данные видео при первом посещении еще не подгружены, неизвестены пропорции сторон. Размер блока с видео будет один, как данные получены, размер блока подстраивается под видео...
Решаю проблему, узнаю размеры кадра видео. Ширину, высоту, заношу в бд к записи публикации. На странице с видео, присваиваю свойство aspect-ratio. К примеру aspect-ratio: 1934/1080.
Все видео преобразовываю(независимо от соотношения сторон) к DAR 16:9, значение SAR адаптируется. Я не совсем понимаю, что именно это, догадываюсь, но утверждать не могу.
Быть может стоит присваивать всем блокам с видео aspect-ratio: 16/9. Будет ли это верным?

«Быть может стоит присваивать всем блокам с видео aspect-ratio: 16/9. Будет ли это верным?» Абсолютно верно, если вы всё-равно кодируете к данному размеру

Если вы всё ещё ориентируетесь на ютуб как на эталон — имейте в виду, что далеко не все видео на нём 16/9: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3N5MlZg_Cdg / https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FtutLA63Cp8

А точно ли вы вставляете видео ? Приведите html. Судя по описанию вы делаете, что-то не так.  Есть тег  у него есть атрибут poster который имеет больший приоритет по загрузке и гарантирует, что вы ничего не наламаете, видео вообще может завтра госпровайдер отключит, а картинку пользователь получит.

Просто блоку родителю этого видео задайте размер высоты, который должен быть и сделайте overflow: hidden, тогда размер будет всегда одинаков, а лишнюю высоту видео он будет обрезать.
